# C#: Find out if the Bluetooth adapter is turned On/Off + the type of the STACK used (Programmatically)

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet

How to programmatically tell if the Bluetooth adapter on the device which is the code is running at, is turned **On** or **Off**?

Discovery methods such as "`cli.DiscoverDevices()`" using **32feet** simply return no device found in both situations which

- The Bluetooth adapter in **On** but no device is available.
- The Bluetooth adapter is **Off**.

Also, I know the visual approach of finding a type of Bluetooth stack in-used from `device manager` in Windows but would like to find out if this is possible to recognize in the code as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Local%20Radio%20Information

e.g. `BluetoothRadio.Mode`, and `Modes` in recent dev versions.

Comment: any method to find out the type of stack being used by any chance?

Comment: The BluetoothRadio.SoftwareManufacturer Property... There's other useful properties there too.

Comment: Fantastic. I really appreciate your response Alan. Somehow I couldn't find an answer for the type of the stack in 32feet and all the solution where around how to find out with visually expecting it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way off the top of my head is to check the device power state. There is a decent writeup here on power states:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554397(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You will need to use pinvoke as the only way to manage power states is via native code.